# VS 2015: The specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

When I try to publish my ASP.NET app to Azure, I get the

> "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters."

error. I see quite a few questions about this and most people are suggesting that we edit the publish profile XML file. I followed some of the suggestions here: [Website publish failing due to file path being too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411136/website-publish-failing-due-to-file-path-being-too-long)

The problem is that whatever I enter, VS 2015 seems to be using another temp folder path.

Is there some global file I need to edit as changing the publish profile for my app doesn't seem to change/override a global setting.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I was able to get it going by adding the following in the publish profile file - the idea is to use a really short folder name:

```
<PublishTempFolderName>i2</PublishTempFolderName>
```

And there are some global settings. This post provides more information about where to find those global settings:

[The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/234)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes to restart visual studio may work.